# In Python, How to convert a date fetched from mySQL to any formatted string like (%d-%m-%Y)

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having a hard time formatting a date in Python, which is fetched from mySQL, into any of the following (%d-%m-%Y), (%m-%d-%Y).    Here are a few routines I thought worked for a while until I saw what they did to my graphic charts.

This is the call:

```
ListOfCoIDs = dennislib.TopMeetingforCompany(clientID,1,2,MeeTs,Servcs)
CoMeetings = []
for co_id in ListOfCoIDs:
    try:
        pp = co_id
        j=0
        meetings = []
        res      = []
        theCOID = pp['coID']
        meetings.append(str(pp['MeetingId']))                     #  0
        print "MEETING DATE = ",pp['Date']
        meetings.append(**EnglishDate**(pp['Date']))                  #  1
        meetings.append(pp['Time'])                               #  2
        meetings.append(pp['Type'])                               #  3
        meetings.append('')
```

And these are the calls which are made from the above EnglishDate

```
def EnglishDate(tme=time.time()):
    print "Incoming date = ", tme, time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    return time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")            #,time.localtime(tme))

def EnglishDatetime(tme=time.time()):
    print "Incoming date = ", tme, time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")   #,time.localtime(tme))

def EnglishDateTime2Date(tme=time.time()):
    print "Incoming date EDT2Date = ", tme, time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    return time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")            #,time.localtime(tme))

def ISODate(tme=time.time()):
    print "ISO date = ", tme, time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")            #,time.localtime(tme))
```

What these do is to replace the date supplied to Today's date.  Yet, when I try it manually, I seem to get the proper date.  Is there some trick for running code?

TIA

Dennis

Comment: Well, how do you get the dates from MySQL and how do you call the functions?

Comment: +1. This functions all return the current time, even if you pass an argument. Check what you are doing with tme

Comment: parsing a date time from MySQL's default format into python timestamp: `time.strptime(mysql_timestamp,  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`. Are you doing anything like this or just sending the returned strings?

Comment: I included the call from the prior stack level, and I will add more code for the mySQL call...

Comment: Sorry guys I got a call from the customer and was not able to respond to you quickly...  I think that I get a dictionary returned from the call to mySQL...

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I fetch a date field from mySQL in the instance above.  I think I tried the "strptime" but had problems with it... not sure...  How does it differ with "strftime"?

Comment: I think the time field gets a string you need to decode it with strptime but it is dependent on the date format returned from sql look at that

Comment: @Joran Beasley Dictionary turns date into string when I use pp['Date'] and you are saying to use strptime to turn it into a date format in Python?  Then strftime() to format it back into a string? Sounds interesting, Joran.  I'll look into that.

Comment: @DennisKean `strptime` - the "p" stands for Parse a date string (into a datetime object). `strftime` - the "f" stands for Format a string (from a datetime object).

Comment: Thanks to all.  I figured it out, now.  I finally understand how the dates are manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the reference to time.

```
def EnglishDate(tme=time.time()):
    print "Incoming date = ", tme, time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    return time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")            #,time.localtime(tme))
```

"time.strftime" should have been "tme.strftime".  I was not acting on the passed parameter.  Instead, I was getting the current date!

Live an learn...  This is what it should have been

```
def EnglishDate(tme=time.time()):
    print "Incoming date = ", tme, tme.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    return tme.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")            #,time.localtime(tme))
```

Thank you all.  You were all helpful... especially @Not_a_Golfer

DK